# Populating a dataframe using an if statement

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
country = c("uk", "fr", "it") 
N = c(100, 80, 95)
df <- data.frame(country, N)
a=4
b=3
c=5
```

I want to assign 'a' to a new 'a_col' column which is added to the database in the 'uk' row.

I want to assign each country's 'a_col' column in turn.  I have got this line of code to work using ifelse:

```
df$a_col <- ifelse(df$country=='uk', a, NA)
```

However, I don't want an 'else' as I want to add each country's value in turn.  Why can't I get this 'if' statement to work?

```
df$a_col <- if(df$country=='uk', a)
```

I know if has something to do with the length of 'df$country=='uk'', but can I rectify this?

Any ideas would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `ifelse` statement if you populate only a subset of your new column:

```
df$a_col[df$country == "uk"] <- a
> df
#  country   N a_col
#1      uk 100     4
#2      fr  80    NA
#3      it  95    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
      `cbind(df, data.frame(model.matrix(~ -1 + country, data = df)))`